# $a+b+c=0$. $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$. Prove that $\frac {1}{-a^2+b^2+c^2} + \frac{1}{a^2-b^2+c^2} + \frac{1}{a^2+b^2-c^2} = 0$

Tags: real-numbers, fractions

The following problem proves how some equations can be solved with very little data.

Let `a, b, c` be real numbers $a, b, c \in R*$ such that $a+b+c=0$.
Prove that

$\frac {1}{-a^2+b^2+c^2} + \frac{1}{a^2-b^2+c^2} + \frac{1}{a^2+b^2-c^2} = 0$

for any `a, b, c` real numbers.

Do not use anything **beyond 8th grade's curriculum and no geometry** to solve this.

I have tried `brute-forcing` it by bringing it to the common denominator. It doesn't work, however, as the expression gets more and more complicated. Neither does writing `a` in terms of `b` and `c` seem to work, as you get sums at the denominators.
The last attempt was to try and prove that the 2 expressions, the **given** one and the **ugly** one are equivalent.

Comment: And also instead of "Do not" it would be more appropriate to use "please do not'(in my opinion)

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Multiplying to a common denominator in the identity gives
$$
(a + b + c)(a + b - c)(a - b + c)(a - b - c)=0.
$$

Comment: What is the common denominator? It looks much longer than yours.

Comment: I mean, It's just the product of the 3 denominators, right?

Comment: The...nominator? That's denominator or numerator. By the way, which x and y?

Comment: I can't say I tried your solution, for I didn't understand it, but ok...

Comment: I mean numerator, sorry. Your equation is $1/r+1/s+1/t=x/y=0$. So it is equivalent to $x=0$. Here $y=rst$ and $x=st+rt+rs$.

Comment: I found another way, proposed by Quantum, under you. I understand that one.

Comment: @DeitrichBurde Yours looks interesting too...But you jumped from a,b,c to r,s,t and then to x,y. I can't see the connection.

Comment: Good for you, but I am sure you can understand that $1/r+1/s+1/t=(st+rt+rs)/(rst)$. Then look at your equation. So take $r=-a^2+b^2+c^2$ etc. So $0=st+rt+ts=(a+b+c)\cdot ...$. And if you assume that $a+b+c=0$ then $1/r+1/s+1/t=0$ and you are done.

Comment: Oh. I now see the simple brilliancy of simplicity, but it's with too many variables.

Answer (score 4):

Hint :$-a^2+b^2+c^2=-2bc$

Now try putting this in the original expression

Comment: Where did you get that equation from? Sorry, I'm not that great with this.

Comment: Algebra to me is like geometry to Photomath.

Comment: @AndrewFNAF   use a=-(b+c) and square both sides

Comment: ...great...I...think...?

Comment: Thanks. I think you forgot a minus in front of the a. Also, That only applies to the first.

Comment: The second one is $2c^2+2bc$. This doesn't look great.

Comment: use b=-(a+c),,,,

Comment: So you just play around with one in terms of the other 2? Brilliant...
I'm not saying that it won't work. It just seemed odd.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aaaaand, it worked.