# If $a+b+c=0$, prove that $\dfrac{1}{b^2+c^2-a^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2+a^2-b^2}+\dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2-c^2}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b+c=0$, prove that $\dfrac{1}{b^2+c^2-a^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2+a^2-b^2}+\dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2-c^2}=0$

$\Rightarrow (c^2+a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)+(b^2+c^2-a^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)+(b^2+c^2-a^2)(c^2+a^2-b^2)=0 \\ \Rightarrow -(b^2-c^2-a^2)(b^2-c^2+a^2)-(a^2-c^2-b^2)(a^2-c^2+b^2)-(a^2-b^2-c^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2)=0 \\ \Rightarrow -[(b^2-c^2)^2-a^4]-[(a^2-c^2)^2-b^4]-[(a^2-b^2)^2-c^4]=0 \\ \Rightarrow -(b^4+c^4-2b^2c^2-a^4)-(a^4+c^4-2a^2c^2-b^4)-(a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2-c^4)=0 \\ \Rightarrow -b^4-c^4+2b^2c^2+a^4-a^4-c^4+2a^2c^2+b^4-a^4-b^4+2a^2b^2+c^4=0 \\ \Rightarrow -a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2=0$

Then I'm stuck. I know $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2$, but the signs are different here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3833419/42969

Comment: Just verify that $-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2=(-a + b + c)(a - b + c) (a + b - c)  (a + b + c).$

Comment: Is this something I can deconstruct from the left hand side or it's just a memory item? Thanks.

Comment: It is necessary to assume that a ≠ 0, b ≠ 0, c≠ 0 for the conclusion to make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have,

$a+b+c=0$

$(b+c)^2=(-a)^2$

$ a^2=b^2+c^2+2ab $

$ b^2+c^2-a^2 = -2ab $

In the given expression,

$ \dfrac{1}{b^2+c^2-a^2} = -\dfrac{1}{2bc} $

Similarly,

$ \dfrac{1}{c^2+a^2-b^2} = -\dfrac{1}{2ac} $

And,

$ \dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2-c^2} = -\dfrac{1}{2ab} $

So our expression reduced to,

$ -\dfrac{1}{2ab}- \dfrac{1}{2bc}-\dfrac{1}{2ac} $

$ = - \dfrac{(a+b+c)}{2abc}$

We have given that, $ a+b+c = 0 $ So,

$ = - \dfrac{(a+b+c)}{2abc} = 0$

Hence proved.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. Just note that

$$a=-b-c$$

$$\Rightarrow a^2=(b+c)^2=b^2+2bc+c^2$$

Then

$$-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2$$

$$=-(b^2+2bc+c^2)^2-b^4-c^4+2(b^2+2bc+c^2)b^2+2b^2c^2+2(b^2+2bc+c^2)c^2$$

$$-(b^4+4b^3c+6b^2c^2+4bc^3+c^4)-b^4-c^4+2b^4+4b^3c+2c^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2b^2c^2+4bc^3+2c^4$$

Collecting like terms, the whole sum collapses to $0$.